# Can fish be caught in all water tiles?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The Halloween update for Minecraft added an actual function for fishing rods; you can actually catch fish with them now! To do so, you right click and you cast the line.

Can fish be caught in all water tiles, or must they be a certain depth, certain number of tiles together, etc?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Fish can be caught in any body of water. Unlike pigs, cows, or chickens, fish don't exist until they're caught, so it doesn't matter where your water is.

You do need a minimum size body of water so that the lure doesn't get stuck on a block -- as long as the bobber is free-floating, you should be good. I've actually managed to cast into water falling from a "spring" block, have the bobber travel up to the top of the falling water, and *then* catch a fish.

Comment: does that mean we can take a bucket of water with us, make a basin, and start fishing whereever we want?

Comment: according to the wiki, yes. I'm trying to verify this for myself. Okay. Just verified it. You do need a minimum size body of water (so that the lure doesn't get stuck on a block -- make sure your pool is at least 2 deep, 2x2 to be safe)

Comment: edit your answer accordingly, then :)

Comment: Notch has said that there will be fish mobs in the future, so this will probably stop working. (Note that the fishing rod can already be used to grab other mobs.)

Comment: You actually *don't* need a minimum size.  I've caught fish in a single block of water.  It just takes practice aiming it right.  :P

Answer (score 4):

From the [Minecraft wiki](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Fishing) as of 1.7:

1. Take a fishing rod.
2. Right click (default settings) while facing a body of water. (**This can be as small as one cubic block**, though the casting method becomes more difficult as your fishing area gets smaller.)
3. Once the float has risen to the water's surface, watch for it to bob under the water.
4. As soon as it bobs underwater, right click again and a fish should fly out of the water towards your feet. (The fish will not always land at your feet, it will sometimes fall short or even fly over you.)

And I have tested this myself, having finally decided to go back to vanilla and try the newest version. I was still able to catch a fish in 1 block of water, though getting the float in was difficult.

Comment: I would love to be enlightened as to why the downvote. If there is a problem with my answer, it can be corrected.

Comment: It offers no additional information that a much earlier answer has given.  You'll even notice the earlier answer has been edited from originally stating that only one block of water was needed, due to the difficulty in getting it to float without sticking to a block.  The addition of the Wiki entry for fishing is helpful, but would better be served as a link in the answer's comments, rather than an answer itself.

Comment: There was a request for an updated answer. And while it is difficult in a single block, it is completely possible and therefore is a valid way to fish. In fact, in any version, that is how I keep supplied with food while traveling. So it's not necessarily easiest, but it is 100% possible to fish in one block of water, and is much easier to accomadate for while travelling, might I add.

Comment: Didn't notice the update request. Fair enough. I didn't vote this down incidentally, but I figured the probable reason for doing so would be that.  So apparently there has been  no change.

Answer (score 4):

In the 1.7.2 update, it does not matter the depth, width or length of your water, you will always have to wait between 100 and 900 ticks (5-45 seconds) every time you cast your fishing rod. That being said, there are some variables that can change the waiting time for finding fish.

- Rain/Snow -- Wait time decreased by 25%
- Indoors/Underground -- Wait time increased by 50%
- Lure Enchantment -- Decreased wait time by 100 ticks (5 seconds)

More information about fishing can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing_Rod#Catching_fish).

Comment: I'll give the bounty to you for giving me detailed info :) I think this explains the results I was seeing that made me think maybe the pool was too small.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Given [Panda's fishing farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aezeY1TCj0M) uses a single block of water and is designed for 1.7, I guess it is safe to say that no given depth or pool size is required.

Answer (score 0):

you can fish in minecraft in 5 steps:
1. Craft a Fishing Rod
2. Make a Boat to Go Fishing
3. Find a Body of Water
4. Go Fishing at Raining Day
5. Cast Fishing Rod and Wait
Then hold your fishing rod in hand, right click on the mouse to cast the rod into water, the bobber floats and can be seen. Then fish is coming and bite the bobber, you can spot spray caused by fish will come towards to bobber and hear a splash sound. As soon as the bobber sink, right click and take back the fishing rod, then fish arrives at your inventory.
For more details you can visit this [mincraft fishing tutorial](http://www.goplay.com/article/how-to-fish-in-minecraft-5-steps-1835.html).